# Proper Spacing Between Elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out which html elements or out of place because I'm wanting the two boxes to have the same spacing from the top as my register form. All the css is correct but not sure what elements are out of place.

Also if you notice on the register form box right below where it says Register For An Account there is a space between the the form area and that title which is not like the template. Why is that?

[Welcome Page](http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/)

[Register From](http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/register)

[Template](http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/Template/login.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `<div class="wrapper">` and `<div class="box">` from your template, right after `<div class="background"></div>`

Comment: So your saying that the wrapper and box divs shouldn't be immediately closed they should contain the rest of the code.

Comment: @JeffDavidson yes, that's it! you can edit it with firebug, opera dragonfly or Google chrome inspector to check it. That should fix it...

Comment: I did that but smudged together. Check out the updated welcome page.

Comment: @JeffDavidson how to you want it to behave: Both at the same level? or One up, the Other down?

Comment: I want them to be on the same level as it was before.

Comment: you have a width css property in the wrapper `width:400px` which makes them stretch, as both _grids_ have `width:48%`, their are taking only **192px**. your template has some *defects*...

Comment: So there's nothing else I can move around maybe something isn't in the right order. Here's the dashboard that shows everything. http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/Template/dashboard.html I'm wondering if there's a better way to display those boxes. So that it'll show up the desired effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7251/discussion-between-nacho-and-jeff-davidson)

Answer (score 1):

`#content-wrapper { top: 250px; }` should do the trick (or something similar to it).